# how to run "only" single test in specflow while running it normally (ignore all tests except one)

Tags: integration-testing, specflow

is there "only" (like in mocha) in specflow to run only this tests and ignore all the others?

I have thousands of tests so don't want to ignore 1 by 1.

I know that I can run only 1 manually, but I mean while running all the tests, to use some API like "only" to run only single test

Comment: What are you using to run it at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement BeforeScenario hook where you could fail tests other than the selected. The selected test could be marked with a tag e.g. 'OnlyThis' -> the logic of failing other test cases would be to verify if they are marked with the required tag.

I believe, there is no build-in option in SpecFlow.

It also depends on the test runner you use. You could filter tests e.g. using the test name.